# Size implications of 1-D array over a 2-D array

Tags: c++

Is there performance or size difference between the the following ways of declaring a large array -

`int a[4000][4000]` and `int a[4000 * 4000]` ? Should we prefer one over the other if possible?

Comment: Have you tried to measure benchmarks before asking?

Comment: The primary difference is with the latter (`a[4000*4000]`) you have to convert 2d indexing to 1d indexing.  With the former, the compiler will perform the conversion.

Comment: There is no size difference.  The C++ language does not add any additional space to the array (except maybe for alignment purposes).  For large arrays, please don't declare them as local, unless you prefix with `static`.

Comment: Unless, you have a weird compiler, do what is most readable. Have you tried to look at the generated assembler code?

Comment: How do I do that?

Answer (score 2):

There's zero difference in memory layout.

Should be no difference in access speed, but you need to measure to be sure.

The 1D array is more versatile. If you want to make a function that can accept arrays of different sizes, with a 1D array you can simply do `void foo(int *arr, std::size_t w, std::size_t h)`. But for a 2D array there's no good solution. Even though their memory layout is the same, attempting to pass a 2D array to such a function would cause UB, just because the standard says so.

If you later decide that you want to allocate the array on the heap, the transition is easier with a 1D array, because you can keep the same `[]` syntax. For 2D arrays, you would either have to use an array of pointers to arrays (which is less efficient), or write a class that wraps a 1D array and overloads `operator[]` (which is the proper way of doing it, but takes time).

Answer (score 0):

Any array is accessed using pointer arithematic by the code generated by compiler in a way like this:

`A[i] == *(&A+i)`

in case of two dimensional array `A[d1][d2]`:

`A[i][j] == *(&A+(i*d2)+j)`

for multi-dimensional arrays it keep getting more complex but internally it is always a linear memory block starting at memory location stored in array variable.

If your code has no row-column logic then it is better to use linear array but if you need that kind of code then it is always better to use multi-dimensional array as per your need because pointer arithmetic can be optimized very efficiently by the compiler.